# Graph Isomorphism property

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I just started a graph theory course, and my *very first* homework problem is the following:

> If $ G \cong H $, show that $v(G) = v(H)$ and $e(G) = e(H)$.

This is confusing to me, because (I think) two isomorphic graphs need not have the same vertices or edges...the sets above just need to be isomorphic, not equivalent. Am I missing something here, or just overthinking the question?

Comment: I guess $v(G)$ and $e(G)$ stand for the cardinality of the sets of vertices and edges

Comment: @dani_s ...of course. I should have read more carefully. Thanks for the response.

Comment: For graphs to be isomorphic means you have a one-to-one correspondence between the graphs preserving the edges.  You can think of this correspondence as a relabeling - the graphs are exactly the same except that the vertices might have different names.  So all the properties of the graphs are the same.

Comment: @JairTaylor I understand what a graph isomorphism is. I mistakenly thought that $v(G)$ and $e(G)$ stood for the actual sets of vertices in edges in $G$, which caused some confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $G\cong H$, by definition of isomorphism, there is a bijection map  $f$ between vertices of $G$ and vertices of $H$. So it implies that $v(G)=v(H)$. Note that $f$ is isomorphism between $G$ and $H$. Thus if $a-b\in G$, then we have $f(a)-f(b)\in H$. By $a-b$, I mean edge between vertices of $a$ and $b$. It is follow from bijection, $e(G)=e(H)$.